# SQL: Calculation of growth percentage of branches considering the merged branches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server:

Table MyData:

| Date | Branch | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220701 | A | 50 |
| 20220701 | B | 40 |
| 20220701 | C | 25 |
| 20230501 | A | 110 |
| 20230501 | C | 35 |

and many dates and branched values in this table.

Table MyMerge:

| OldBranch | MergedIn |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | A |
| C | C |

My goal is to write code that gives the following output:

| MergedIn | Growth |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.22 |
| C | 0.40 |

For example: the growth of A between 1 Jul 2022 (A+B before the merge) and 1 May 2023 is  (110-(50+40))/(50+40) = 0.22

```
SELECT m.MergedIn as MergedIn, (sum(b.Value)-sum(a.Value))/sum(a.Value) as Growth
From MyMerge as m
Inner join MyData as a on a.branch=m.OldBranch
Inner join MyData as b on b.branch=m.OldBranch
Where a.date=20220701 and b.date=20230501
Group by m.MergedIn
```

But my code calculate like this:

A=(110-50)/50 !!

Comment: where does `a.date` and `b.date` comes from ?

Comment: Excuse me. I edit my query...

Comment: `a.date=20220701`? Are you storing your dates as a numerical data type? Why not use a `date`? A column called `date` that's an `int` is an "odd" choice; it's very specifically *not* a date.

Comment: My dates are Numerical for at because my national calender doesn't support by SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.Date, m.MergedIn, SUM(d.Value) Val 
    FROM MyMerge m
    INNER JOIN MyData d ON m.OldBranch = d.Branch
    WHERE d.Date IN ('20220701', '20230501') AND m.MergedIn IN ('A', 'C')
    GROUP BY d.Date,
             m.MergedIn
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte.MergedIn, CAST((val - LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY cte.MergedIn ORDER BY cte.Date)) AS DECIMAL) / LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY cte.MergedIn ORDER BY cte.Date) Growth
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2 WHERE cte2.Growth IS NOT NULL
```

Yields:

```
MergedIn    Growth
A           0.22222222222
C           0.40000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but it calculate for all dates. I have only growth between 2 manual date. we have too many data in MyData Table in several date and branches. what can we do?

Comment: @MohammadSaeidi Added the necessary WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

If I understand the question correctly and you want to calculate the growth for each branch between two periods, a statement using `LAG()` function is a possible solution to your problem:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyData
FROM (VALUES
   (20220701, 'A', 50),
   (20220701, 'B', 40),
   (20220701, 'C', 25),
   (20230501, 'A', 110),
   (20230501, 'C', 35)
) v (Date, Branch, Value)  

SELECT *
INTO MyMerge
FROM (VALUES
   ('A', 'A'),
   ('B', 'A'),
   ('C', 'C')
) v (OldBranch, MergedIn)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Date, MergedIn,
   (Value - LAG(Value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MergedIn ORDER BY Date)) * 1.0 / 
   LAG(Value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MergedIn ORDER BY Date) AS Growth
FROM (  
   SELECT md.Date, mm.MergedIn, SUM(md.Value) AS Value
   FROM MyData md
   LEFT JOIN MyMerge mm ON md.Branch = mm.OldBranch  
   GROUP BY md.Date, mm.MergedIn
) t
```

Result (without rounding):

| Date | MergedIn | Growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220701 | A | *null* |
| 20230501 | A | 0.222222222222 |
| 20220701 | C | *null* |
| 20230501 | C | 0.400000000000 |

**Update:**

If you need to analyze the data only for two periods, you may try an approach based on conditional aggregtaion:

```
SELECT 
   MergedIn, (Value1 - Value2) * 1.0 / Value2 AS Growth
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      mm.MergedIn, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN md.Date = 20230501 THEN md.Value END) AS Value1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN md.Date = 20220701 THEN md.Value END) AS Value2
   FROM MyData md
   LEFT JOIN MyMerge mm ON md.Branch = mm.OldBranch  
   GROUP BY mm.MergedIn
) t
```

Result (without rounding):

| MergedIn | Growth |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.222222222222 |
| C | 0.400000000000 |

Comment: but it calculate for all dates. I have only growth between 2 manual date. we have too many data in MyData Table in several date and branches

Comment: @MohammadSaeidi, if you want to calculate the differences between two dates, you may try an approach based on conditional aggregtaion.